# How to prohibit certain words in a json value with cerberus

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, cerberus

Lets say that I have this json:

```
{"name": "John"}
```

And I want to restrict the json from containing the substring "my name is", so if I receive:

```
{"name": "my name is John"}
```

Cerberus will me that the json is not correct and I can display the correct output, so far I have tried the `"forbidden"` field but it does not work, because forbidden only takes the exact phrase, this is how I have so far the cerberus validation:

```
{
  "name":{
    "type": "string",
    "minlength":1,
    "forbidden":["my name is"],
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you will want to use [check_with](https://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/validation-rules.html#check-with) alongside a simple function to forbid what you want to exclude e.g.

```
def cleanName(field, value, error):
    if 'my name is' in value:
        error(field, 'error message')
```